# Initializing struct with json partial information

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, nlohmann-json

Supposing a struct `A` which has 7 member element:

```
struct A {
    bool m_a;
    std::string m_b, m_c;
    float m_d, m_e;
    double m_f;
    time_t m_g;

    A() = default;

    A(
        bool a, std::string b,
        std::string c, float d,
        float e, double f, time_t g
    )
        : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c),
        m_d(d), m_e(e), m_f(f), m_g(g) {};
};
```

And a `nlohmann::json` where information are stored from the API call:

```
nlohmann::json j = {
    {"a", "true"},
    ...
    {"g", "1660228853"}
};
```

The API call at best provides all the keys representing the elements of struct `A`.
In case one or more elements are not provided how to initialize the structure efficiently?

Comment: What do you want the elements to be initialized to in that case?

Comment: "NaN" for std::string; Some nan value for numeric;

Comment: I was thinking about iterating with `for (auto& [key, val]: j.items())` and overwrite default initialized arguments. But is it an efficient way?

Comment: There is no NaN value for `bool` or `time_t` and `"NaN"` may be a valid string, so it shouldn't be used this way. It seems like you really want to replace the members with `std::optional`s.

Comment: ok, but how to handle the casting errors while passing the json content to the constructor?

Comment: I was thinking about passing to the constructor all the json elements as `std::optional<std::string>` and then, if each of them has value apply the casting if needed. But, is it efficient?

Comment: The default-constructed `std::optional` is empty. So you can just iterate the json as you suggested and set the corresponding member. I am not sure what exactly you want to know about efficiency. This does not look like a place where micro-optimization is necessary. In any case you'll probably want to `std::move` the strings out of the json though (to avoid an allocation/copy), assuming you don't need the json object anymore afterwards.

Comment: As each of the member elements has a "m_" suffix, I am simply stuck because I cannot write `a["m_" + key] = std::move(val);`. Should I overload the operator [], or I am simply missing something very easy?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said "iterate". You need to assign each element one-by-one with their corresponding name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion that is not particularly tuned to high performance *(why do you need the efficiency?)*.

It is implemented by overloading `from_json` from the nlohmann::json library, see [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#arbitrary-types-conversions).

Because C++ does not have introspection, you must implement a `switch` statement or several `if` blocks to map the json keys to your member names.

You could maybe contrive a solution using a map and setters, but this is probably overengineered.

As for default parameters for your struct, you could

- either initialize all variables that you do not ever want to be uninitialized in the constructor of `A`, or
- you initialize them in the function that creates an instance of `A` from a json file, or
- you could leave them uninitialized. This is a bit dangerous, but might be ok for your use case, I don't know.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;

struct A {
    bool m_a;
    std::string m_b, m_c;
    float m_d, m_e;
    double m_f;
    time_t m_g;

    A() = default;

    A(
        bool a, std::string b,
        std::string c, float d,
        float e, double f, time_t g
    )
        : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c),
        m_d(d), m_e(e), m_f(f), m_g(g) {};
};

void from_json(const json& j, A& a) {

    // set default values for all members if 
    // you don't want uninitialized variables.
    // Or alternatively initialize all variables
    // in ctor

    // overwrite values from json
    for (auto& [key, value] : j.items()) {
        if (key == "a") {
            a.m_a = value;
            continue;
        }
        if (key == "g") {
            a.m_g = value;
            continue;
        }
        // ...
    }
}

int main() {

    json j = {
        {"a", true},
        {"g", 1660228853}
    };

    A a = j.get<A>();

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a.m_a << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.m_g << std::endl;

    // values not contained in j will be uninitialized,
    // unless you handle them appropriately
    std::cout << a.m_d << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
true
1660228853
-7.66069e-28
```

Give it a go on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/qaed4P8Kr